# How to separate sum() of positive and negative numbers into other rows

Tags: sql, oracle

table1

```
-------------
|  a  |  b  |
-------------
| -1 |  1  |
|  5 |  3  |
| -4 | -4  |
|  6 |  7  |
|  9 | -2  |
-------------
```

Answer

```
negative :
positive :
```

**EDIT:**

It's a special condition to not use `union`.

Comment: You should take a look at the keyword `HAVING`.

Comment: what are the values you're expecting to see in your output, based on your input data? Are you summing all negative values regardless of whether they're in column a or b, or are you summing for each column separately?

Comment: Please explain your "special condition".

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a `CASE` wrapped in a `SUM`

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (a int, b int)
INSERT INTO #TestData (a,b)
VALUES
 (-1,1)
,(5,3)
,(-4,-4)
,(6,7)
,(9,-2)
```

Query

```
SELECT 
 SUM((CASE WHEN A > 0 THEN A ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN B > 0 THEN B ELSE 0 END)) Positive
,SUM((CASE WHEN A < 0 THEN A ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN B < 0 THEN B ELSE 0 END)) Negative
FROM #TestData
```

Output

```
Positive    Negative
31          -11
```

If you need it in two rows, try this

```
SELECT 
 'Positive' DataType
,SUM((CASE WHEN A > 0 THEN A ELSE 0 END)) A
,SUM((CASE WHEN B > 0 THEN B ELSE 0 END)) B
FROM #TestData
UNION ALL
SELECT 
 'Negative' DataType
,SUM((CASE WHEN A < 0 THEN A ELSE 0 END)) A
,SUM((CASE WHEN B < 0 THEN B ELSE 0 END)) B
FROM #TestData
```

Result

```
DataType    A   B
Positive    20  11
Negative    -5  -6
```

Or this

```
SELECT 
 'Positive' DataType
,SUM((CASE WHEN A > 0 THEN A ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN B > 0 THEN B ELSE 0 END)) Result
FROM #TestData
UNION ALL
SELECT 
 'Negative' 
,SUM((CASE WHEN A < 0 THEN A ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN B < 0 THEN B ELSE 0 END)) 
FROM #TestData
```

Result

```
DataType    Result
Positive    31
Negative    -11
```

Ok, without UNION you can use unpivot like this

```
SELECT 
DataType
,result
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
     SUM((CASE WHEN A > 0 THEN A ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN B > 0 THEN B ELSE 0 END)) Positive
    ,SUM((CASE WHEN A < 0 THEN A ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN B < 0 THEN B ELSE 0 END)) Negative
    FROM #TestData
) pr
UNPIVOT
(
    result
    for DataType in (Positive, Negative)
)u
```

Result

```
DataType    result
Positive    31
Negative    -11
```

Comment: Thanks. But me need in 2 rows:

Comment: @RomanVoitseshevskyi I've just updated my answer, see if that resolves it for you

Comment: @RomanVoitseshevskyi I've provided an answer that uses unpivot rather than union. give it a go.

Comment: The **unpivot** solution is superior to the **union** solution, because it requires only one pass through the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as 
(
    select a as ab from tablename
    union all
    select b from tablename
)
select 'positive', sum(ab) from cte where ab > 0
union all
select 'negative', sum(ab) from cte where ab < 0
```

Comment: Why without the union? If you ask a complete question and mention every restriction you have it will stop people providing an answer only for the goal posts to be changed with things like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SIGN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions164.htm#SQLRF06106) function for grouping:

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(x) >= 0 THEN 'positive:' ELSE 'negative' END as sign, SUM (x) as result
    FROM (SELECT *
            FROM TABLE_NAME UNPIVOT (x FOR y IN (a AS 'a', b AS 'b')))
 WHERE x <> 0
GROUP BY SIGN (x)
```

And without PIVOT ;)

```
  SELECT CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN 'positive:' ELSE 'negative' END SIGN, 
         SUM (CASE SIGN (a)WHEN rn THEN a ELSE 0 END + 
              CASE SIGN (b) WHEN rn THEN b ELSE 0 END) result
    FROM TABLE_NAME x
         JOIN (    SELECT ROWNUM - 2 rn
                     FROM DUAL
               CONNECT BY LEVEL < 4) y
            ON rn <> 0
GROUP BY rn
```